# How to ssh-copy-id 2nd key when the server only allows publickey authentication

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

[MacOS 10.12.6 host, Ubuntu 14.04 LTS guest]

I have a local VM setup to only accept publickey authentication.  Until now, I've been using a key that requires a passphrase to be entered, and the arrangement works fine. However, I now need to setup a script to automatically perform a scp for me.

As I neither want to have the script pause for me to provide the passphrase nor use `expect` to do that automatically, I've decided to use a second key that does not have a passphrase.

It appears to me that `ssh-copy-id` is not able to handle this situation as it uses the `-i` parameter to tell it which key to upload, and therefore I cannot specify which key to login with.

So, my question is, how to get `ssh-copy-id` accept a second key that would be used to login in the first place?  Should I use `ssh-add`?

*(In light of my above hick-up with `ssh-copy-id`, I've manually copied  and added the key to my authorized_keys file.)*

Answer (score 24):

`ssh-copy-id` appends keys to the remote `authorized_keys` file. To add several specific keys, run it once per key with `-I <key-file-name>`.

**Update**

After your comment, I think I got your question wrong.

You want to use one key to authenticate while installing another on your server.

`ssh-copy-id` does not offer a command-line option to choose a key for authenticating while executing `ssh-copy-id`.

But it passes `-o` through to `ssh`. So:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/<your-new-id-to-install> -o 'IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your-already-existing-id>' <servername>
```

You can also use `ssh-agent`, in which case you won't have to enter your passphrase when using `ssh`, `scp`, `ssh-copy-id`, a.s.o. for as long as `ssh-agent` is running.

Comment: The problem is that I need to be able to login before I can upload the key.  But, since I have the server configured to only accept public key login, there is a chicken/egg situation.

Comment: i like the ssh-agent solution

Comment: your order for ssh-copy-id is wrong. it should be the new id in -i and the existing/working one in the IdentityFile region

Comment: not sure why but this didn't work for me.  It kept submitting the `~/.ssh/<your-already-existing-id>` to the server rather than the identity I wanted to submit

Comment: This didn't work. In my scenario, I have ssh password access blocked, and I have ssh access with one user. But I'm trying to copy the public ssh key of ANOTHER USER, so I can't log in to that account and transfer its public key

Answer (score 7):

I add the same issue so I'll share my success story, which is an improvement over @sborsky's answer. You will not need ssh-agent nor complicated tricks.

While doing the command suggested, I got the following:

```
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: WARNING: All keys were skipped because they already exist on the remote system.
    (if you think this is a mistake, you may want to use -f option)
```

And actually yes, it's a mistake by ssh-copy. Just use the `-f` switch and will work:

```
ssh-copy-id -f -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub -o 'IdentityFile ~/ssh-private-key.key' user@server.domain
```

You will see (amongst other things) the important line: `Number of key(s) added: 1`

Now you will be able to connect using key-based SSH-authentication: `ssh user@server.domain`

Comment: The approach with `-f` works but will also create duplicates.

Comment: Because you're forcing it. If the previous key didn't worked, either delete it or force it, and `then` delete it.

Comment: yes I know, that was just a comment to specify the behavior, which was not explained in your original answer. It was way easier to handle inside my scripts with temporary ssh-agent in the and and also limits the key password request to the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 3):

Using `ssh-add` to add your key to the agent is definetly an option.
Otherwise I believe you'd have to set up an entry in the [.ssh/config](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssh_config) file which includes an IdentityFile option, this will tell ssh how to authenticate for that server and allow ssh-copy-id to do its thing.

Comment: Though I am using `config`, I haven't tried your suggestion yet.

Answer (score 3):

As others said, I think your best option is to use ssh-agent, like this:

1. Enable ssh-agent

   ```
   eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
   ```

   *Note the `ssh-agent -s` command starts the SSH agent and generates environment variables (that's why we feed the output to the `eval` command).*
2. Load the 1st key (the one you currently use to log into the remote system)

   ```
   ssh-add <1st-key>.pub
   ```
3. Run the `ssh-copy-id` command and pass the new (2nd) key as a parameter

   ```
   ssh-copy-id -i <2nd-key>.pub <user>@<host>
   ```

   Et voilà... you have your 2nd key copied (ssh-copy-id used the ssh-agent transparently to authenticate with the first key).
4. *[OPTIONAL]* You may now shut down the ssh-agent if you wish:

   ```
   eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I took it to my hands. Completely manually done. Now, the aim is to create the .pub key in remote home and append it to authorized_keys file there. Here are the details:

```sh
# Variable definitions
identity_file=<already authorised key that you want to use for authorising>
ssh_keyfile_path=<new key path. we will add .pub below>

# Copy the public key into the remote server's authorized_keys 
# file using the ssh-copy-id command. Note: This doesn't check 
# if the key already existing.

echo " Copying public key (temporarily) to the remote host.."
scp -i ${identity_file} ${ssh_keyfile_path}.pub ${ssh_remote_user}@${ssh_remote_ip}:~

# We use basename to get the remote filename ($remote_key_pub)
echo " Appending to the authorized_keys"
remote_key_pub=`basename ~/${ssh_keyfile_path}.pub`
ssh ${ssh_remote_user}@${ssh_remote_ip} "cat ${remote_key_pub} >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"

echo " Removing the (temporary) public key"
ssh ${ssh_remote_user}@${ssh_remote_ip} "rm ~/${remote_key_pub}"
```

Hope this helps.